# If input value equals specific string add class

Tags: jquery

I know there is some topics similiar to this one. But those didnt hel me.
I have html like this:

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-143[]" value="customer service">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">medicine</span>
 </label>
</span>
```

For now I have jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("input").val() == "customer service") {
      $(this).addClass("cust-serv");
  }
});
```

What I whand to do is add Class to input when it has specivic value. In this example this value is "customer service" and I want to add class "cust-serv".

Can You help me with that?
Thx!

Comment: Do you also want it JS to check when the value changes or just when document is ready? If not you need to reference the addClass() to a specific element not `$(this)`

Comment: `$(this)` is not what you think it is ...

Comment: an if - statement does not create its own context. You are adding the class to the document

Answer (score 2):

1. Loop through all the input so you can use the context `this`

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "customer service") {
    $(this).addClass("cust-serv");
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-143[]" value="customer service">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">medicine</span>
</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` does not refers to your input field. So instead of using `this` use `"input"` again

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("input").val() == "customer service") {
      $("input").addClass("cust-serv");
  }
});
```

Though I would suggest you to use some more specific class as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "this" is not linked to your class so replace :

```
$(this).addClass("cust-serv");
```

with :

```
  $("input").addClass("cust-serv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do by using

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("input").each(function(){
if($(this).val() == "customer service"){
 $(this).addClass("cust-serv"); 
}});
 });
```